# Getting classnotfound exception error while deserializing the object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, classnotfoundexception, xml-deserialization

I am getting below error while deSerializing and object.

```
13:47:00,679 INFO  [stdout] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1) 2012-10-26 13:47:00,679 () DEBUG com.dipp.testMap - Error while reading the object to HashMap
13:47:00,680 ERROR [stderr] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl from [Module "deployment.DIPP.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
13:47:00,682 ERROR [stderr] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1)     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
13:47:00,682 ERROR [stderr] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
```

Here is my code.

```
        try{
         transferObject = (HashMap)o.readObject();
            }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             log.debug("Error while reading the object to HashMap");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

I have a field called EPOCHDATE which is in the transferObject and has XMLGregorianCalendar datatype.Any ideas to resolve this issue? I am getting classNotFound exception . I believe, I have to add dependency in the POM file.

Thanks in advance

Gendaful

Comment: It's very likely a classpath issue.  As you stated, check your POM file and/or classpath.

Comment: Instead of being lazy, you could have tried adding the dependency to your POM file before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. I have added below dependency to my POM.xml

```
<dependency>
```

xerces
   xercesImpl
   2.8.1